# Bash Script Function Output /dev/null

Tags: shell-script, tmux, function

I'm working on a bash function to check if a tmux session is running.  The function works but if no session is running it outputs "failed to connect to server".  How do I output that error to null without appending 1>&2 to every function call?

```
tmux_checker()
{
    if [ -z $(tmux ls  | grep -o servercontrol) ]
    then
        tmux new -d -s servercontrol
    fi
}

tmux_checker #> /dev/null 2>&1 or 1>&2
```

Comment: “without appending 1>&2 to every function call?”, suggests to me that you want a way to append it once, to affect all functions. But this does not match the accepted answer. Did you mean “without it affecting every function”

Comment: @richard as far as I can tell, the OP calls `tmux_checker` multiple times in the script and didn't want to have to call it as `tmux_checker 2>&/dev/null` each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redirect the output in the function itself:

```
tmux_checker()
{
    if [ -z $(tmux ls 2>/dev/null | grep -o servercontrol) ]
    then
        tmux new -d -s servercontrol
    fi
}

tmux_checker
```

Answer (score 2):

To test for an existing `tmux` session (and start a new one in the background if none exists), use

```
if ! tmux has-session 2>/dev/null; then
    tmux new-session -d
fi
```

To check for a session with a specific name:

```
if ! tmux has-session -t name 2>/dev/null; then
    tmux new-session -d -s name
fi
```

As a shell function:

```
start_tmux () {
    set -- "${1:-servercontrol}"

    if ! tmux has-session -t "$1" 2>/dev/null; then
        tmux new-session -d -s "$1"
    fi
}
```

This may be used as

```
$ start_tmux
```

or

```
$ start_tmux mysession
```